# Add timestamp to knife logfile

Tags: chef-infra

Does anyone know how to add a timestamp for log entries in chef-knife.log and get a similar syntax to that of chef-client.log?

```
CentOS 5.8
\#> knife --version Chef: 10.14.2
```

Comment: Just a FYI to the folks who voted to close this: read the tag wiki for [tag:chef] - it's actually on-topic. And it has nothing to do with [cooking.se].

Comment: All the log files for Chef should include a timestamp, since they use the native Ruby logger.